# (ASDF 3) Is it possible to recursively load systems in subdirectories?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I know about using `:module`s, but what about when systems get nested?  Suppose I have the following structure, relative to some unknown user directory:

```
foo/
-foo.asd
-bar/
--bar.asd
```

This could arise, for example, when using Git submodules.  How shall I configure the `(defsystem)` call in `foo.asd` to load `bar` as a dependency, without modifying a config file outside of `foo/` or demanding particular placement for the `foo/` tree itself?  Feels like it should be simple.

**3 Feb. 2020:** From @Svante's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60025623/12808416), it sounds like my question is really 'How do I dynamically ensure that `foo/` and `bar/` both get into the `*source-registry*`?'  The [ASDF manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Configuration-API) makes me think this should do the trick:

```lisp
(asdf:initialize-source-registry 
  '(:source-registry 
    (:tree "«absolute-path-to-foo»/")
    :inherit-configuration))
```

though I have not seen an example of that usage.

**26 Mar. 2020:** The technique above seems to work fine, so I'm closing this question.  ASDF 3 is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASDF doesn't care about relative locations of `.asd` files.  ASDF systems and their dependencies are completely orthogonal to file/directory structure and oblivious to any source version control.

It just looks in several locations for `.asd` files.  Each such file then may contain definitions for systems.  It will generally recurse into the configured folders, so any `.asd` file in a git submodule would usually also be found.

The definitions, e. g. of components, inside of an `.asd` file then work relatively from the location of that file.

In your example, if you give a `:depends-on ("bar")` option to the `"foo"` system, it would just work, no matter where `bar.asd` resides (as long as it is somewhere where ASDF finds it).

A bit more awareness would be required if you have several versions of a library.  This might happen if you work on "foo" and "bar" at the same time, while a stable version of "bar" is also available, e. g. in a quicklisp dist.  Then the lookup order comes into play, but usually your “personal” directories have precedence over “system” directories, so again, it would *just work*.  For more control, you might want to look into `qlot`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  My problem appears to be in getting ASDF to "find it" in the first place.  Am I correct that the least hacky way is to invoke `initialize-source-registry`?  I understand that the old days one might push a value to `*central-registry*`, but that that way is deprecated now.

Comment: I think the least hacky way is to use the standard locations.  I put my projects under `~/common-lisp/`, for example.  Take a look at the ASDF manual for other standard locations and the lookup order.

Comment: Sure, that sounds like best practice, and isn't hacky at all.  But when used as a [scripting language](http://fare.tunes.org/files/asdf3/asdf3-2014.html), Lisp may not ascertain file placement before build-time.  Thus, I need to be able to use a function call.  I've updated my original post to show a form that _seems_ to work(?).